# Generar HTML con Python

Tags: html, python, string, web

Estoy intentando generar un HTML con Python, lo que que deseo mostrar solo es una cadena, pero por alguna razón no toma en cuenta la cadena, espero puedan ayudarme

```
def html_create(self,result):
    template = open("template.html","r")
    output = open("us.html","w")
    text = template.read().format(get_result = result)
    html = output.write(text)
    template.close()
    output.close()
```

& en mi templeate lo recivo de la siguiente manera

```
<p> (get_result) </p>
```

Comment: Depende de qué lenguaje uses para los templates. Me da la sensación de que no estás usando ninguna biblioteca concreta para ello, sino que simplemente estás leyendo el "supuesto template" con un simple `read()`, por lo que tienes es una cadena python. En esa cadena usas el método `format()`, estándar de python para cadenas, el cual espera que las variables vayan entre llaves. Es decir, tu template debería contener `{get_result}` en algún sitio. En cualquier caso te recomiendo que uses algo como jinja2, por ejemplo, para mayor flexibilidad y potencia en el template.

Comment: De echo lo estaba utilizando & ya tenia esta parte, pero no puedo utilizar librerías que deban ser instaladas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código funciona. Lo he probado de la siguiente forma:

Fichero "html.py":

```
def html_create(result):
    template = open("template.html","r")
    output = open("us.html","w")
    text = template.read().format(get_result = result)
    html = output.write(text)
    template.close()
    output.close()

html_create("hola mundo")
```

Fichero de entrada "template.html":

```
<p>{get_result}</p>
```

Fichero de salida "us.html":

```
<p>hola mundo</p>
```

Comment: Si, era la manera en como recibía la variable, tengo otra duda, resulta que mi variable que recibe tiene tabulaciones & saltos de linea, pero al momento de enviarla no lo respeta & sale todo de corrido ._.